# object in session: Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, session, object

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['dbo'] = NEW PDO('sqlite:database.db3');
```

gives:

`Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0`

but putting it to ordinary variable gives no error. All I try to do is to put object into session so it is initialized once.

Comment: if you intent to establish a persistent connectio to your databse you should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php As far as I can renember it does __NOT__ cover PDO, but it will give you some basic insights on the topic

Answer (score 6):

Some objects cannot be serialized and stored in `$_SESSION`.

If your intent was to store a database connection in session for reuse, don't follow that undertaking: it doesn't work.

From [PHP reference on serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php):

> [...] serialize() handles all types, except the resource-type. You can even serialize() arrays that contain references to itself. Circular references inside the array/object you are serializing will also be stored. Any other reference will be lost.

Comment: Why is that so? What is their difference to the 'normal' objects? Does adding a serialize() help?

Comment: And these include Resources. In this case, a PDO object will almsot certainly include a resource (like the database handle)

Comment: @Simon - Adding a __serialize() won't help. If PHP can't serialize it naturally, then it can't serialize it using serialize()

Comment: @Mark — oh, sorry. was thinking of adding __sleep() and __wakeup() functions. Confused it with __serialize(). Would those help?

Comment: @Simon You would have to subclass `PDO` and add those overloaded methods. The exception in your case is thrown in the ctor, though!

Comment: @Simon - You could add a __sleep that disconnected from the database, and a __wakeup that reconnected to the database.... but remember that you need that __sleep needs to return a complete list of properties from the object that need to be serialized, so you'll have to extract that property list, and ensure that it contains all the information needed to reconnect... you may well need to extend PDO with a wrapper class to hold this additional information