# Baffled: PHP Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I have found that one common reason for the error is [an exception being thrown from within an exception handler](http://www.wamped.org/post/2174829567/exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-lin). I'm quite sure this doesn't happen in the application I'm trying to debug... But I've put all the initialization processing lines at the top of index.php in a try/catch.*

It can apparently also happen because [some things cannot be serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440640/session-saving-problem-getting-php-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stac) [to be stored in a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624223/object-in-session-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknow). At most this application stores arrays into the session (quite a bit), but I'm confident that it doesn't store anything too out of the ordinary in it.

Someone commented that it happened to them because their primary key [needed to be CHAR(32) instead of INT(11)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795527/425767). The PK's in this app are all INTs.

Other suggestions are that it could be a problem with [PHP 5.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440640/session-saving-problem-getting-php-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stac) [fixed in 5.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662159/how-do-i-track-down-an-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-lin), [full disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7482211/425767), and a [need to typecast a SimpleXML value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php#101502). We do happen to be running PHP 5.3.3, but upgrading would have to be a last resort in this case. It hasn't always been doing this.

UPDATE/NOTE: I actually can't reproduce the error myself, only see it happening in the logs, see below paragraph for where I *believe* the error is happening...

* From the error logs, it seems likely that at least one place it is happening is index.php. I am deducing this only because it is indicated in some entries by a referring URL. The try/catch code is currently only around the "top" initialization portion of the script, below that is mostly the HTML output. There is some PHP code in the output (pretty straightforward stuff though), so I may need to test that. Here is the catch part, which is not producing any output in the logs:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log(get_class($e)." thrown. Message: ".$e->getMessage(). "  in " . $e->getFile() . " on line ".$e->getLine());
    error_log('Exception trace stack: ' . print_r($e->getTrace(),1));
}
```

Would really appreciate any tips on this!

EDIT: PHP is running as an Apache module (Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler). I don't think there are any PHP accelerators in use, but it could just be that I don't know how to tell. None of the ones [listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) are in phpinfo().

As far as I can tell the MPM is prefork. This is the first I'd ever looked into the MPM:

```
# ./httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

Comment: Are you tossing off an exception from inside a destructor?

Comment: Can you reproduce this reliably? If so, I'd try running the offending code outside of a web server, if possible, or under something basic, like CGI. I have a vague recollection that I've had this error, and it was something to do with the MPM I was running PHP under.

Comment: @DampeS8N, I'm confident there's no exception code in a destructor, the app doesn't really make too much use of destructors if at all..

Comment: @halfer, this reminds me of one of the worst parts about this. I can't reproduce it myself :( :( ... I can load all scripts fine, but the error log is LOADED with these Fatal Errors throughout the day, every day now. So apparently a certain percentage of visitors are able to trigger it :(

Comment: Ah, I think that was the case for me also (on a much earlier PHP version, mind). Would it be trivial in your case to change the MPM in your web server or to change your accelerator? Or maybe to upgrade each, if they're not on the latest versions? (If you would edit your question to note your current MPM and accelerator versions, that might be relevant).

Comment: @halfer, I've updated the post with what I could determine for the MPM (prefork) and accelerator (none)...

Comment: Hmm, well at this stage I'd plump for the least invasive live change that you can do - maybe if you're using mod_php then switch to fcgid? obviously test it all first, but this is a much less onerous change than switching your PHP version imo. If you've got a test server, you could try these changes on it and then hit it repeatedly with `ab` to see if you can get it to replicate.

Comment: Are you using [`register_shutdown_function`](http://us.php.net/register_shutdown_function)? Exceptions thrown from inside a shutdown function look like this.

Comment: Have you tried turning on error_reporting(E_ALL);. There may be another error before the fatal errors that might give the game away. (Ensure ini_set("display_errors", "off"); if the site's in production!)

Comment: In order to work out where the offending exception is being thrown, you could grep the source code for all instances of `throw`, and replace them with a call to a function that logs the error and only then throws the exception.  That should at least give a better error message than "unknown on line 0".

Comment: Is the problem reproducible? So if you call a script with certain arguments does the error always occur? Does the script its job? (e.g. do you get the expected output in browser)?

Comment: @groovenectar: did any of the given comments help?

Comment: @DCoder it's not using register_shutdown_function(), tried a search for that per the wamped.org article

Comment: @Robbie, all errors, notices, warnings etc are going into the logs, so we do see all those error types (it's where the exception error is coming up)... Not sure if there's anything that can be changed to get even more logging?

Comment: @Brilliand, there aren't any exceptions in the app being manually thrown with `throw` :-(

Comment: @DCoder, so far nothing mentioned or found has helped fix this particular error, but I haven't lost hope... I'll definitely make sure a bounty is set when the answer is flagged, even if I have to reopen the bounty (hopefully that's possible)

Comment: @yankee, I most unfortunately can't reproduce it myself. It is plaguing the error logs though throughout the day, from different IP addresses. The pages are loading fine for me but apparently not for all visitors...

Comment: If you have other notices and warnings in the log, my suggestion is to program them out. One notice _might_ be causing the problems, and if not, it'll remove the mess making it tricky to spot "one-off" errors.

Comment: @groovenectar: sorry to hear that, I was hoping my idea of shutdown functions would be helpful.

Comment: Well, then try to find similarities. At the beginning of every request you get, write the current timestamp and print_r(get_defined_vars()) to a log file. Or even better: let `tcpflow` running so that you have a complete dump of the http headers. Then try to identify the correct log file and position on log file by the timestamp whenever an error occurs in your error log. Reconstruct the exact http request header and send this to your server. Maybe that'll help you to reproduce.

Comment: @yankee Great tips!! I've got a log going in 3 spots on index.php, it's already provided some insight to a seemingly smaller issue... I'm definitely interested in trying `tcpflow` as well, but not entirely sure where to start with it but have found a few articles and downloads

Comment: @groovenectar: Just create a directy, cd in this dir and execute `tcpflow "port 80"` as root. This will create lots of files. Find the file you want by the file creation timestamp. Beware that on a busy server the amount of data this creates will be huge.

Comment: @yankee, you're the man!! Pinpointed it using the log output... There were a couple `SimpleXMLElement`s stored in the session. But, catch is that it would only happen on a visit with an IP that had never been there before, so I would not notice any of my own requests triggering it!! Looking forward to trying out tcpflow at some point as well.... Now, I am not seeing an option to "Start a Bounty" again, do you know if there's another way I can award you more points (had a 50 rep point bounty that wasn't replenished)? Would you just like to create an answer that I'll then accept?

Comment: @groovenectar: Well, there is your answer. It is way longer so that it is more useful to other people with similar problems and google skills. I am curious about your story. Please let us know. You can edit my answer adding a section "results in this case" or something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The problem

In short you have a exception thrown somewhere, you have no idea where and up until now you could not reproduce the error: It only happens for some people, but not for you. You know that it happens for other people, because you see that in the error logs.

### Reproduce the problem

Since you have already eliminated the common reasons you will need to reproduce the error. If you know which parameter will cause the error it should be easy to locate the error.

- Most likely it is enough if you know all the POST/GET parameters.
- If you can't reproduce with just these, you need to know additional request headers. Such as user agent, accept-encoding,...
- If you still can't reproduce, then it becomes very difficult: The error may depend on a state (a session), the current time, the source ip address or the like.

#### The custom log method

Let's start simple: To get all parameters you can write in the very beginning of the affected php file something like:

```
file_put_contents("/path/to/some/custom_error_log", date()."\n".print_r(get_defined_vars(), true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Don't forget that the custom_error_log file must be writable to your php application. Then, when the error occurs in the error log, find the corresponding lines in your custom_error_log file. Hopefully there are not to many requests per second so that you can still identify the request. Maybe some additional parameters in the error log like source ip can help you identify the request (if your error log shows that).
From that data, reconstruct a request with the same POST/GET parameters.

#### The tcpdump method

The next option that is very simple as well, but requires you to have root-access on your target machine is to install tcpflow. Then create a folder, cd into that folder and simply execute (as root) `tcpflow "port 80"`. The option (port 80) is a pcap filter expression. To see all you can do with that, see `man pcap-filter`. There is a lot what these filter expressions can do.

Now tcpflow will record all tcp connections on port 80, reconstruct the full data exchange by combining the packages belonging to one connection and dump this data to a file, creating two new files per connection, one for incoming data and one for outgoing data. Now find the files for a connection that caused an error, again based on the timestamp in your error log and by the last modified timestamp of the files. Then you get the full http request headers. You can now reconstruct the HTTP request completely, including setting the same accept-encoding, user-agent, etc. You can even pipe the request directly into netcat, replaying the exact request. Beware though that some arguments like a sessionid might be in your way. If php discovers that a session is expired you may just get a redirect to a login or something else that is unexpected. You may need to exchange things like the session id.

#### Mocking more things

If none of this helps and you can't reproduce the error on your machine, then you can try to mock everything that is hard to mock. For example the source ip adress. This might make some stunts necessary, but it is possible: You can connect to your server using ssh with the "-w" option, creating a tunnel interface. Then assign the offending ip adress to your own machine and set routes (route add host  ) rules to use the tunnel for the specific ip. If you can cable the two computers directly together then you can even do it without the tunnel.

Don't foget to mock the session which should be esiest. You can read all session variables using the method with print_r(get_defined_vars()). Then you need to create a session with exactly the same variables.

#### Ask the user

Another option would be actually ask the user what he was doing. Maybe you can follow the same steps as he and can reproduce.

#### If none of this helps

If none of that helps... well... Then it gets seriously difficult. The IP-thing is already highly unlikely. It could be a GEO-IP library that causes the error on IPs from a specific region, but these are all rather unlikely things. If none of the above helped you to reproduce the problem, then you probably just did not find the correct request in all the data generated by the custom_log_file-call / tcpflow. Try to increase your chances by getting a more accurate timestamp. You can use microtime() in php as a replacement for date(). Check your webserver, if you can get something more accurate than seconds in your error log. Write your own implementation of "tail", that gives you a more accurate timestamp,... Reduce the load on the system, so that you don't have to choose from that much data (try another time of day, load of users to different servers,...)

### circle the problem once you can reproduce

Now once you can reproduce it should be a walk in the park to find the actual cause. You can find the parameter that causes the error by trial and error or by comparing it to other requests that caused an error, too, looking for similarities. And then you can see what this parameter does, which libraries access it, etc. You can disable every component one by one that uses the parameter until you can't reproduce anymore. Then you got your component and can dive into the problem deeper.

Tell us what you found. I am curious ;-).

Answer (score 4):

I had such an error, too. Found out that I returned a sql object in my session class (that was used by the session_handler) instead of returning nothing or at least not the sql object. First look into your _write and _read methods, if you too return some incorrect stuff.

[Notice: ... Unknown on line 0 - How to find correct line, it's NOT "line 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076899/notice-unknown-on-line-0-how-to-find-correct-line-its-not-line-0)

Comment: That's a good tip, thanks... We aren't using any custom session handlers though for this app :(

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question has already been answered, but I'll add this since it may help someone:

I managed to (unintentionally) produce errors without a stack frame from a function which used its own error handler to maintain control of execution while calling a potentially "dangerous" function, like this:

```
// Assume the function my_error_handler() has been defined to convert any
// PHP Errors, Warnings, or Notices into Exceptions.

function foo() {
    // maintain control if danger() crashes outright:
    set_error_handler('my_error_handler');

    try {
        // Do some stuff.

        $r = danger();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $r = 'Bad Stuff, Man!';
    }

    restore error_handler();
    return $r;
}
```

The "untraceable failure" would happen *at the end of the program execution* if the logic in "Do some stuff" returned from foo() directly, bypassing the call to restore_error_handler(). What I took away from the experience is this:

1. PHP maintains a *stack* of error handlers which gets deeper/taller with each call to set_error_handler().
2. Bad Stuff can happen if you push error handlers onto the stack and don't clean up after yourself before the program exits "normally".

This was a tough bug to isolate - I basically narrowed the problem down to the above function and then stared at it until my eyes bled.

So how would I have tracked this down, knowing what I know now? Since I don't know of any way to inspect the PHP error handler "stack" directly, I'm thinking it might make sense to use a Singleton object to encapsulate all set/restore operations for PHP error handlers. At least then it would be possible to inspect the state of the Singleton before exiting the program normally, and if "dangling" error handlers are detected to generate a sensible failure/warning message before PHP freaks out.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping code in a try/catch block, what happens when you register an exception handler? Clearly your try/catch block is not catching the exception, thus resulting in the errors logged to Apache. By registering a handler, you can be sure any uncaught exception is handled.

Also, if you're using namespaces in your application, make sure you write \Exception in your catch block (or include the Exception class via a use statement).

Comment: Darn! I put this at the top of the initialization script:

`function my_exception_handler($e) {
    error_log(get_class($e)." thrown. Message: ". $e->getMessage(). "  in " . $e->getFile() . " on line ". $e->getLine());
    error_log('Exception trace stack: ' . print_r($e->getTrace(), 1));
}
 
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');`

Verified that it does catch exceptions, and just a few minutes ago another came in!

`[Mon May 21 09:48:39 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0`

I had high hopes for this one as well..

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late but one issue I discovered when moving a site from a local to a remote server. I was using Concrete5 cms had developed my site locally(windows 8 in xampp) and then uploaded to a remote server running Cent 0S

Windows mysql by default is case insensitive and created a lower case database. Once this was uploaded to the remote server I received the "Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0?"

I then corrected the database tables case and my site started working again.

Comment: Argggh! I really hate that case insensitive/sensitive problem :(

Comment: StackOverflow is a repository of knowledge to help all readers, rather than a forum to help the OP, so it's never too late to add something that might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

For us, this error was due to inadvertently serializing SimpleXML objects.

If you are using SimpleXML objects with 5.3.3, make sure you are are casting the node values to whatever you need (e.g. string) if you are serializing the values in the session.

**Before**:

```
  $token = $response->Token->Value;
  /* token saved in session, results in line 0 error */
```

**After**:

```
$token = (string) $response->Token->Value;
  /* token saved in session, no error */
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I think that was the case here too

Answer (score 1):

I had completely the same error. A very spacial case: if you connect an unnamed function (closure) hook to an object instance's hook point. After that you try to serialize this object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error after filling the Illuminate Eloquent model's Fillable property incorrectly. Note the last 3 elements of the array, one is **missing a coma**.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'budget',        
    'routestatus' ,
    'userroutenumber'
    'totalmovingseconds',
    'totalidleseconds'
];
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm surprised that wasn't a Parse Error -- perhaps Illuminate is doing something additional in the context of models. I wonder if it has something to do with the way it does caching

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it appeared upgrading server from centos 5 to centos 6 and downgrading PHP from 5.4 to 5.3. Actual issue was PHP apc, not configured properly. Check your APC. I was using Symfony2, so you might find some help at [Symfony Unable to allocate memory for pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363612/symfony-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool)

Answer (score 0):

one simple way to produce this error is an old server with `register_globals = On`. then you only need two lines of code:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION["my_var"] = "string";
    $my_var = new MyClass(); //could be any class, i guess
?>
```

as soon as you reload this page once, you'll get the `Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0` - error. seems like there is a conflict between the instance of the class and the (session) variable.
at least this is how i got this annoying error which is so hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for me when I changed the namespace on a few Symfony bundles. Deleting the files in the the symfony cache directory fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have a corrupt/inconsistent table in the database. Try dumping the database. If you get a error that's the time. Repair that table and the issue should go away.

It is for this reason why clean install works. The clean install is just that clean.

mysqlcheck should work but if it does not show and issue still do above.