# Symfony Unable to allocate memory for pool

Tags: php, memory, symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is causing “Unable to allocate memory for pool” in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/what-is-causing-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool-in-php)

Today I noticed the next error:

```
ErrorException: Warning: require() [function.require]: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in /symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugClassLoader.php line 82
```

Its a strange error, if I reload the page sometimes 2 files has this error, other times all the files.

It is in my JS and CSS files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This error is usually related to Alternative PHP Cache (APC) related which is a free and open opcode cache for PHP. Its goal is to provide a free, open, and robust framework for caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code. Edit /etc/php.d/apc.ini, enter:

```
# vi /etc/php.d/apc.ini
```

Make sure the mktemp-style file_mask to pass to the mmap module is correct and valid one:

```
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
```

Next make sure the size of each shared memory segment, with M/G suffix is set correct as per your requirements. In my case it was set to 8M:

```
apc.shm_size=96M
```

You need to adjust the number of seconds a cache entry is allowed to idle in a slot in case this cache entry slot is needed by another entry:

```
apc.ttl=3600
```

The number of seconds a user cache entry is allowed to idle in a slot in case this cache entry slot is needed by another entry:

```
apc.user_ttl=3600
```

The number of seconds that a cache entry may remain on the garbage-collection list.

Save and close the file. Make sure you adjust the values as per your requirements. Restart the Apache 2 web server:

```
# service httpd restart
```

Comment: Sometimes, the issue can be resolved by just clearing the cache:
    php app/console cache:clear

Comment: As mentioned above, clearing the cache can help, but I also had to restart apache for it to resolve itself.