# Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0, session_start

Tags: php, mysql, session, exception, pdo

**Another Update! 2/2/13**
Updated PHP to version 5.3 and it now gives me this message,

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep() #1 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

However, I'm not using the serialize or unserialize function...

**Update!**

This works, but it is the incorrect and ugliest way of doing it. And I don't want to do it like this, but I figured that it might help

```
$db    = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=dbname;", "user", "pass");
public function login($user, $pass) {
    global $db;
    //stuff
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I just switched over my project files to my web host (it works perfectly locally).

I'm getting this error, Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0.

It is oh so helpful. I am only including one file right now, it's a class with one function which counts the IDs of the entered username and password and then either returns true or false depending on what it found. (1 = true, anything but 1 = false).

I'm using PDO (mysql), and if I don't connect to my database I don't get the error but if I remove the session_start(); from the top of my document I also don't get the error.
    private $db;

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=dbname;", "user", "pass");
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

And this is where I set the session,

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $errors = array();
    if($user->login($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"]) === false) {
        $errors[] = "Username or password is incorrect";
    }
    if(empty($errors)) {
        $_SESSION["user"] = $_POST["user"];
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

I am not actually throwing an exception, anywhere. I don't know what this error means. I am running PHP Version 5.2.17

Here is my login function,

```
public function login($user, $pass) {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :user AND `password` = :pass");
    $sql->bindParam(":user", $user);
    $sql->bindParam(":pass", $pass);
    $sql->execute();

    return ($sql->fetchColumn() == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Index page (error occurs on every page that uses session_start, index page and login page)

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}else {
    //begin HTML, no more php after this (except the closing bracket)
```

Comment: why not use try-catch ? and see error by getMessage() ?

Comment: What makes you think that would be helpful at all? The code is working, it connects to the database, it checks if the username and password entered is correct, it sets the session, it redirects if the session isn't set. All in all, it's working perfectly except it's giving me that error for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: did you upgraded mysql version ?

Comment: I am running version 5.5.23-55 of MySQL. This has something to do with sessions, because when the sessions isn't set, I don't get the error.

Comment: A bit more code would help.

Comment: Right, that is practically all the PHP code. I added the index page's PHP code. The login PHP code looks the same just reversed, so if the session is set it will redirect to the index page, along with the $_POST checks that I already posted.

Comment: Possible [duplicate][1] of an older thread?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485371/baffled-php-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-l

Comment: Not even remotely a duplicate. That guy is actually throwing an exception, all of my code (except the html) is in my original post. Do you see me throwing an exception? Furthermore, the ID is an integer, $_POST["key"] can be stored in sessions and I'm not running version 5.3.3 of PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I renamed the session to "username" instead of "user" and then it started working. I called my user class for $user so I guess something went terribly wrong when I tried to name a session the same. Which is still terribly weird because $user is a variable and "user" is a string >_>

Anyways, problem has been resolved, thank you PHP for being rather dumb sometimes.

**Update**

The culprit this entire time was register_globals in the PHP.ini. It was turned off on my local server but it was turned on, on my host.

It's turned off now though, everywhere. I thought I might add this in case some runs into this problem in the future.